# Permutations at most x duplicates in article

Tags: permutations

Let's say we have 50 numbers (1 - 50).
Each data set contains 5 numbers.

How many sets are there, where there are at most x duplicates between two sets.
No duplicates within a set are allowed.

Example with less data;
Let's say we have 10 numbers:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Let's say a set contains 4 numbers.

We want all sets with at most 2 duplicates between two sets.

- 1,2,3,4
- 1,2,5,6
- 1,2,7,8
- 1,2,9,10
- 1,3,5,7
- 1,3,6,8
- 1,4,5,7
- etc

I don't even know where to begin with the calculation.

Comment: When you say two duplicates, do you mean one pair or two pairs?  How about a set of three?  Which of $(1,1,2,2),(1,1,2,3),(1,1,1,2)$ have two duplicates?  None of your examples have any duplicates at all.  It would be good to give some that do.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I don't mean duplicates within a set, but duplicates compared to another set. So:
(1,2,3,4,5)
and
(1,2,3,6,7)
have 3 duplicates (both have 1,2 and 3) and this is not valid. 

(1,2,3,4,5)
and
(1,2,6,7,8)
only have 2 duplicates (1 and 2) and is valid.